# Maintaining same state variable to implement Show More/Less functionality

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

I am having a page with multiple cards, where each card has a list of items.I have been trying out the implementation of Show More/ Show Less implementation on each of the card. For a single card, I am getting it right by adding two properties to the state object. But if I implement the same for all the cards, I end up adding more state object properties one for each card.
Looking out for a better way, where I can use one common to handle all cards Show More/Less implementation

Just need an efficient approach to achieve this.
Help would be appreciated

### Component Code

Example with only two cards

```
import * as React from 'react';
interface IState{
  arr1:[],
  arr2: [],
  arr1ExpandFlag: boolean, // For updating Button label(More/Less)
  arr2ExpandFlag : boolean
  arr1temsToShow: number,  // Number of items to show
  arr2itemsToShow: number 
  //I will end up adding two variables one for each card
}
export default class App extends React.Component<{},IState> {

  constructor(props:any){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr1 :[],
      arr2 :[],
      arr1ExpandFlag: false,
      arr1ExpandFlag: false,
      arr1itemsToShow: 3,
      arr2itemsToShow: 3,
    }
  }

  showMore = (type: string) => { // end up adding if conditions
    if(type === 'arr1')
    {
      (this.state.arr1itemsToShow === 3) ? 
      (this.setState({ arr1itemsToShow: this.state.arr1.length, arr1ExpandFlag: true })):
      (this.setState({ arr1itemsToShow: 3,arr1ExpandFlag: false}))
    }
    if(type === 'arr2')
    {
      (this.state.arr2itemsToShow === 3) ? 
      (this.setState({ arr2itemsToShow: this.state.arr2.length, arr2ExpandFlag: true })):
      (this.setState({ arr2itemsToShow: 3, arr2ExpandFlag: false}))
    }
  }

 render()    // This is just for two cards
 {
   return
   (
      <div> 
        <div>
          {this.state.arr1.slice(0, this.state.arr1itemsToShow).map((data : any, i) => 
            <p key={i}>{data.user}</p>
          )}
          <a onClick={() => this.showMore('arr1')}>
            { (this.state.arr1ExpandFlag) ? 
              ( <span>Show less</span>)   : 
              ( <span>Show more</span>)
            }
          </a>  
        </div>
       <div>
         {this.state.arr2.slice(0, this.state.arr2itemsToShow).map((data : any, i) => 
             <p key={i}>{data.user}</p>
         )}
         <a onClick={() => this.showMore('arr2')}>
          { (this.state.arr2ExpandFlag) ? 
            (<span>Show less</span>)   : 
            (<span>Show more</span>)
          }
         </a>  
      </div>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

Comment: Think of React as a library for creating Components that can be reused multiple times in your application. Why not creating a component which will display the items with two links `Show less` / `Show more`, this component would have a single state variable to know if the user is showing less or more items

Comment: @OlivierBoissé is right. It seems like you are overcomplicating things by using different state attributes for parts which are the same but just duplicate. Try to build resuable components instead. Like a `Card` component which has `state.isExpanded`, a method to toggle this attribute and then render as much of them as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said - build it out into reusable components. Start by identifying places where you're repeating yourself and extracting those out. It becomes easier with practice.

I would start with Card. You can use a card type (you could also use an interface but this is personal preference) and then add an onClickExpand handler to form the Props for this control.

```
type Item = {
  user: string;
}

type Card = {
  items: Item[];
  expanded?: boolean;
  numItemsShowing: number;
}

type CardProps = Card & {
  onClickExpand: () => void;
};

const Card = (props: CardProps) => {
  const { expanded, items, numItemsShowing, onClickExpand } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {items.slice(0, numItemsShowing).map((data, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{data.user}</p>
      ))}
      <a onClick={onClickExpand}>
        {expanded
          ? <span>Show less</span>
          : <span>Show more</span>
        }
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then your app can be simpler:

```
type State = {
  card: Card[];
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state = { cards: [] };

  showMore = (index: number) => () => {
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards.map((card, i) => {
        // Only modify card if it's the index we care about
        if (i === index) {
          return {
            ...card,
            expanded: true,
          }
        }
        return card;
      })
    });
  }

  addCard = () => {
    const newCard = {
      items: [],
      expanded: false,
      numItemsShowing: 0
    };

    this.setState({
      cards: [ ...this.state.cards, newCard ] // add to end of array
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.cards.map((card, i) =>
          <Card
            {...card}
            onClickExpand={this.showMore(i)}
            key={i}
          />
        )}

        <button onClick={this.addCard}>Add Card</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This app lets you click the button to add a new card into the state.